# Using webpack externals causes 'require is not defined' error in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-externals

I'm trying to develop a custom react component and I want to publish it on npm later. I've got the following webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, args) => {
  entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  externals: {
    react: 'commonjs react'
  }
}
```

When running in the browser, I get `'require is not defined'`. Why does webpack bundle a require statement? If I remove externals from the config, everything runs alright.

**EDIT:**
By running in the browser, I mean that I've created a client project for the lib using npx create-react-app. There, I've imported my bundle via an import statement.

Comment: Which output are you trying to use?  `commonjs` means that a `require()` will be available because that is part of the CommonJS spec.

Comment: Can yoe elaborate how you run it in the browser exactly?

Comment: @EmrahIzci I've updated the question.

Comment: @zero298 I want it to be importable by others using npm. So, I guess you are right, that's the cause. But shouldn't my client project transform the require statement then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by exposing the library as Universal Module:

```
libraryTarget: 'umd'
```

And specifying externals like this:

```
externals: [{
  'react': {
    root: 'React',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    commonjs: 'react',
    amd: 'react'
  }
}, {
  'react-dom': {
    root: 'ReactDOM',
    commonjs2: 'react-dom',
    commonjs: 'react-dom',
    amd: 'react-dom'
  }
}],
```